# SCSS How do I remove additional Height from div?

Tags: html, css, sass

I've created a card that is showcasing an article.

For some reason, two of the elements have additonal height that's causing weird behaviour. At first I thought it was the image but giving it a `diplay:block` hasn't solved the issue.

I've been messing around with it a lot so it's a bit of a mess at this point. SO here's the weird extra height between the white part of the card and the image:

[image: Unwanted additional height shown by super useful red arrow]

Because it's happening to two elements, I have a feeling that it's something important that I am fundamentally missing.

The two affected elements are:

- `articleCard_image`, a  `<div>`
- `articleCard_container`, a `<section>`

The issue only occurs for the `<secction>` when the 'Read Article' anchor is displayed. (I've commmented out the `display:none` which is changed to `block` on hover)

I'm using Gulp to compile the scss to css.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you! Code shown below:

SCSS:

```css
.articleCard_container {
    width: 55.7rem;
    height: auto;
    
    .articleCard_image {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: block;

        .articleCard_category {
            position: relative;
            bottom: 4rem;
            left: 3rem;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 1.4rem;
            color: var(--white);

            width: 100%;

            p {
                font-weight: 600;
            }

            .thumbtack {
                margin-right: 1rem;
                margin-bottom: 1rem;
            }

            .purpleRose {
                width: 100%;
                display: block;
            }
        }
    }

    .articleCard_textContent {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 1rem 3rem 5rem 3rem;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: var(--white);

        .articleCard_date {
            color: var(--articleDate);
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 1.2rem;
            
        }

        .articleCard_title {
            margin-top: 1rem;
            font-size: 1.6rem;
            width: 100%;
            color: var(--articleTitle);
            font-weight: 700;
        }

    }

    .articleCard_readMore {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: var(--buttonPrimary);
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        font-weight: 600;

        position: relative;
        bottom: 2rem;
        left: 3rem;

        // display: none;
    }


}

.articleCard_container:hover {

    .articleCard_readMore {
        display: block;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```html
            <div class="carouselle_container">
                <section class="articleCard_container">
                    <div class="articleCard_image">
                        <img class="purpleRose" src="./assets/purpleRose.jpg" alt="purple rose">
                        <div class="articleCard_category">
                            <img class="thumbtack" src="./assets/thumtack.svg" alt="thumbtack icon">
                            <p>featured news / category</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="articleCard_textContent">
                        <time date="2020-03" class="articleCard_date"> march 20th 20xx</time>
                        <h3 class="articleCard_title">This is an example of a really long heading that needs to span over multiple lines.</h3>
                    </div>
                    <a class="articleCard_readMore" href="/">read article</a>
                </section>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to give the .articleCard_image position relative to make sure that the category does not overflow and then give the .articleCard_category absolute position and give a full width and height and display block to the img in order to take the entire space

```css
.articleCard_container {
  width: 55.7rem;
  height: auto;
  
  .articleCard_image {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      position: relative;
      img{
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .articleCard_category {
          position: absolute;
          bottom: 4rem;
          left: 3rem;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          
          text-transform: uppercase;
          font-size: 1.4rem;
          color: var(--white);

          width: 100%;

          p {
              font-weight: 600;
          }

          .thumbtack {
              margin-right: 1rem;
              margin-bottom: 1rem;
          }

          .purpleRose {
              width: 100%;
              display: block;
          }
      }
  }

  .articleCard_textContent {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 1rem 3rem 5rem 3rem;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: var(--white);

      .articleCard_date {
          color: var(--articleDate);
          text-transform: uppercase;
          font-size: 1.2rem;
          
      }

      .articleCard_title {
          margin-top: 1rem;
          font-size: 1.6rem;
          width: 100%;
          color: var(--articleTitle);
          font-weight: 700;
      }

  }

  .articleCard_readMore {
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: var(--buttonPrimary);
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      font-weight: 600;

      position: relative;
      bottom: 2rem;
      left: 3rem;

      // display: none;
  }


}

.articleCard_container:hover {

  .articleCard_readMore {
      display: block;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```